# How to find duplicates in Excel and list in second column with the similar value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Implementing a new inventory program, and I'm trying to locate duplicate SKU's in a complete Excel export. All SKU's have similar (like) values in them. For Example one SKU is `ABC123` and the next few SKU's there's SKU: `QWABC123WBI` which are the same exact SKU's.

I need away to bring them side by side of all similar values or How do I locate "like" Values in Excel 2007 on one column and display it side by on another column.

For example, These are the values/cells column `A`
**productid/sku**:

```
ABC123, 
QWABC123WBI,
ASCABC123FWF,
QWEEVSDVB444,
FT43TGGGYHHRTH,
GHTRGHY5Y,
```

So the in column `B` and `C` it should displays:

```
**DUPLICATE 1   DUPLICATE 2**:
QWABC123WBI,    ASCABC123FWF
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a VBA macro like this:

```
Const storeColumn As Long = 1    'This defines to column number of your data

Sub findAllLikes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, storeColumn), ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, storeColumn))

    Dim cell As Range, dupCell As Range
    Dim dupColumn As Long, str As String

    For Each cell In r
        If Trim(cell.Value) <> "" Then
            dupColumn = storeColumn + 1
            For Each dupCell In r
                If cell.Row <> dupCell.Row Then
                    str = Trim(cell.Value)
                    If (Right(str, 1) = ",") Then str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
                    If (dupCell.Value Like "*" & str & "*") Then
                        ws.Cells(cell.Row, dupColumn).Value = dupCell.Value
                        dupColumn = dupColumn + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can run the macro by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: I tried it and it gave me an Error.  I added 3 SKU's to Column A (for example: ABC123,
QWABC123WBI, ASCABC123FWF and the common denominator is " ABC123" because they have multiple SKU of the same product) and to column B added your code... Error.  Anything I doing wrong? I was thinking a macro might do the trick?

Comment: Your help is Much appreciated............. But it's still not working. I have 15,000 SKU's in column A1:A15000 ....... and I need to know all the "like" to be listed in each adjacent column to help narrow the duplicates. They all have a common denominators or similarity to them in the core of the SKU.

Comment: `Run-time Error '1004'  application -defined or object-defined error` ... Any idea what that is?

Comment: @JoeSmith I forgot the first line ;).

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Your a genius! Thank you... you saved my bacon ;) Question, can you add to the code to look all of A column and to keep adding to right rows if `Like` value is found in column? But it should only connect on same row that it found on that row and keep adding downwards for all SKU's if `like` value is located?

Comment: @JoeSmith It will be another question, so ask it in a new question ;).